# netbeans cordova- error while building my project

Tags: git, cordova, ssl, netbeans, build

I have some problems on my newtbeans Cordova installation.

I try to build the simple Cordova Hello World project to check it on my device.

but when i try to build my projet, netbeans return me this error:

```
Error: Command failed: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "git clone "https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device.git" "C:\Users\hadrien\AppData\Local\Temp\git\1426857416149""
```

Cloning into 'C:\Users\hadrien\AppData\Local\Temp\git\1426857416149'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device.git/': SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

```
at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:744:12)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:1008:16)
at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:1176:11)
at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
at Pipe.close (net.js:476:12)
```

C:\Users\hadrien\Documents\NetBeansProjects\HTML5Application\nbproject\build.xml:235: exec returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)

I feel a bit lost, can you help me? maybe i made something wrong during my installation?

Thx a lot

Comment: What is the version of your npm  ?  
try "npm --version" in command line.  And try to have the latest version . npm install npm -g

Comment: 2.5.1,and still the same after update...

Comment: Could you please start over and issue the following commands from the command line ;  
Go to a path where you want to create your phonegap project.
1) phonegap create appName --id com.apps.appName  --name appName
2) Then say "phonegap build android" 

What happens as a result ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try to do this!
Open the **cmd** and put this:

```
git config --global http.sslVerify false
```

press enter! Ready!

Comment: Worked! GG wp, you made my day ;-)